# JPA Mapping - Can I have a "composite" relationship?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Let me introduce you to my current problem. I have this system where **users** can join many **chat rooms**.

In the **model** layer, I have the following classes:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String fullName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_room")
    private Set<Room> rooms;

}
```

```
public class Room {
    
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rooms")
    public Set<User> users;
}
```

So far, we're doing good (I suppose), but there's a problem with the next feature. In this feature, a user can set a list of his favorite rooms.

Question:
Which is the best way to implement an `n-m relationship` between two entities, where there is **more than one field** associating them?

I need something like this:

```
public class User {

    private Set<Room> rooms;
    private Set<Room> likedRooms;

}
```

```
public class Room {

    private Set<User> users;
    private Set<User> likes;

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about this, but why not have 2 joining tables, one containing the liked rooms, and the other containing the other rooms?

Comment: As vlad mentioned, have another table (USER_LIKES) with 2 columns: UserId, roomIds. where UserId would be one-to-one with user table and roomid would be many-to-many with room table

Comment: Yeah, from my point of view this is the most fitting solution. But like you guys, I'm not sure too... I'll try this approach for now. Thank you, gentlemen!

Comment: Little off-topic: I'd rename the mappedBy values to User:"user_rooms" and Room:"room_users". The additional ones as suggested should then be named User:"user_likedrooms" and Room:"room_likedbyusers". This way it is far more obvious and unambiguous. Also, if you manage some rooms independently (room can exist without belonging to users), you should pay attention to the removal behaviour (removeOrphans and the like).

Comment: Is `likedRooms` supposed to be a subset of `rooms`?